# How can I know the missing drivers after fresh installation of XP?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I just got a computer off the street, and it's super good.
It doesn't come with a system, so I installed XP. After installation, hardware manager shows yellow notifications on parts like LAN, grapic card, chipset.

Is there an utility I can use to find out the kind of drivers I should download by examining the hardware?

Comment: look in the device manager for clues to the hardware type. When it comes to getting it right everytime, you want to open it up and identify the motherboard, and any plug-in cards.

Comment: If laptop, lookup the support page of the model and you should find the drivers. Best to start with the basics; Chipset, Video, Audio and LAN/WLAN. If desktop, open the side and look at the motherboard model. Go to the manufacture and do the same. You should have any missing drivers narrowed down quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several resources, of the most common: [DriverFinder](http://driverfinderpro.com/) and [DriverGuide](http://www.driverguide.com/).

Its also very easy to search for drivers yourself.  [Google](https://www.Google.com) is the search engine I use most, but you can also use [Download (or CNET)](http://download.cnet.com/windows/drivers/) to find what you are looking for.

Comment: (You already did (you up-voted and marked my answer as correct)).